Why WebAssembly that use AES-256-GCM in C++ using openssl slow significantly, compared to native JavaScript?
Background:
I used the pbkdf2Sync algorithm for encryption, implementing it in C++ with OpenSSL and then converting it to WebAssembly. However, I found that the WebAssembly implementation runs slower than the JavaScript version.
Reference:

Why wasm slow than JS - devtools reason

Practice:
Due to sensitive information contained in the code, it cannot be disclosed publicly. However, details about the performance in Chrome and the runtime in Node.js are available. Here is a summary:

The underlying C++ code uses the openssl PKCS5_PBKDF2 algorithm, which has been encapsulated. The actual benchmark can be seen in the attached images.
The C++ encapsulated algorithm and the pbkdf2Sync process implemented in V8 are essentially the same, both utilizing AES-256-GCM. JavaScript glue code was automatically generated using emcc.
The attached images include benchmarks of the C++ calling openssl, a comparison between Node and WASM calls, and the performance within the browser.

Relatives:

C++ Benchmark:


Node vs Wasm:


Emcc Makefile:


Call in Node:


Chrome Performance:



